# WP localization: how to translate 2 merged pugins?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, localization

Since some days I've been struggling with an issue regarding plugin translation.
I have  a free plugin version and use:

```
function my_plugin_l10n(){
load_plugin_textdomain( 'free-plugin', false, dirname(plugin_basename( __FILE__ )).'/languages/');
}
add_action('plugins_loaded','my_plugin_l10n');
```

I then have an add-on that depends on the free one, and adds features and screens to the free version, sometimes merging functions in the free pages, sometimes creating new pages. How do I combine the translation files? I've always used translation plugins such as '*codestyling localization*' or '*loco translate*' but never had to deal with this scenario.

I've tried several ways such as:

```
function addon_l10n(){
 load_plugin_textdomain( "addon", false, dirname(plugin_basename( __FILE__ )).'/languages/');
}

add_action('plugins_loaded','addon_l10n');
```

OR

```
function addon_l10n(){
load_plugin_textdomain( "addon", false, ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/my_free_plugin/languages/' );
}
add_action('plugins_loaded','addon_l10n');
```

I tried to merge manually the po strings but no success, in the plugin pages only the strings coming from the free version are translated (the localized files "**free-plugin-{locale}.po, free-plugin-{locale}.mo**" are in place in the /free/languages/ dir.)

I've also tried to use the same textdomain across the 2 plugins but do't know if correct and where to store the po-mo files..

So actually I'm very confused..
can anybody help?

Comment: any idea anybody?

Answer (score 0):

Each plugin should have its own textdomain and its own language files (.po, .mo), so you should rewrite `addon_l10n()` like this:

```
function addon_l10n(){
    load_plugin_textdomain( "addon", false, dirname(plugin_basename( __FILE__ )).'/languages/');
}
add_action('plugins_loaded','addon_l10n');
```

The fact that one is the addon of the other doesn't affect this. Each plugin's .po/.mo files should contain the texts used in the respective plugin, even if they seemingly share some strings.

You might say that a shared string will need to be translated twice, but that's exactly why most translation tools (such as Poedit) implement some kind of [Translation Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_memory).

Comment: It looks like your answer is replicating my first statement, that's the first attempt made but no way, it does 'nt work. The addon functions are (de-facto) extensions of the free plugin, functions and pages are "embedded" in the free one and the only translated strings are the one contained in the  free/languages/free{locale}.po.mo. The strings located in addon/languages/addon{locale}.po.mo are completely ignored. At the moment the only way I found to translate the addon is to merge the strings in the "free" .po and use "free" as textdomain in both the plugins. Not a best practice, I know..